# How can I convert the dates returned by FinancialData into decimal representation?

Tags: curated-data, date-and-time, conversion, finance

I'm trying to run a regression using `Fit` on the output of `FinancialData["SPY", "Jan. 1, 2011"]`.  However, the dates returned from `FinancialData` are not in a format that is recognized by `Fit`. The function returns dates in the format `{y,m,d}`, and I need the dates to be expressed in decimal form.  I'm relatively new to Mathematica, but I've got to believe there's an easy way to transform the list provided by `FinancialData` into one that has the format of `{<date in decimal>, price}`.  Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

```
data = FinancialData["SPY", "Jan. 1, 2011"] /. {d_List, v_} :> {AbsoluteTime@d, v};
model = a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d  x + e;
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d, e}, x]
modelf = Function[{x}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]
Plot[modelf[x], {x, Min@data[[All, 1]], Max@data[[All, 1]]}, Epilog -> Map[Point, data]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Better  (tick labels showing dates)

```
data = FinancialData["SPY", "Jan. 1, 2011"] /. {d_List, v_} :> {AbsoluteTime@d, v};
model = a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d  x + e;
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d, e}, x]
modelf = Function[{x}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]

p = Plot[modelf[x], {x, Min@data[[All, 1]], Max@data[[All, 1]]}, 
       Epilog -> Map[Point, data]];
s = AbsoluteOptions[p, Ticks] /. {o_ -> s_List} :> s;
s1 = s /. {v__, w__} :> {(MapAt[
     If[# != "", 
          DateString[DateList[#], {"Month", "/", "YearShort"}], 
          Null] &, 
     #, {2}] & /@ v), w};
Show[p, Ticks -> s1]
```

[image]

---

Or, using `DateListPlot`, with the model sampled at the original dates:

```
DateListPlot[{data, Table[{d, modelf[d]}, {d, data[[All, 1]]}]}, 
   Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  That's perfect!  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I was thinking of using `Show[DateListPlot[data], Plot[(* stuff *)]]` myself (and the `AbsoluteTime[]` transformation being done only within the fitting function) for the purpose of making the dates as tick, but this is nice. `AbsoluteTime[]` is a neat thing...

Comment: @Brett Nice edit. Thanks!